# Наихудший делитель

Tags: python, python-3.x

Будем считать, что число **а** лучше числа **b**, если сумма цифр числа **а** больше суммы цифр числа **b**, а в случае равенства сумм, если число **а** меньше числа **b**.

Дано число **n**. Найдите такой его делитель **d**, что любой другой делитель **с** числа **n** лучше, чем **d**.

Пример:

```
Ввод: 10
Вывод: 10
Ввод: 239
Вывод: 1
```

Я понял, что здесь нужно считать нули. Вот мой код:

```
a=input()
b=0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if int(a[i])==0:
        b+=1
if int(a)<10:
    print(a)
elif b==0:
    print(1)
else:
    print(a)
```

Не проходит дальше 4-го теста..

Comment: Согласно определению, нужен худший делитель, т.е. наибольший из имеющих наименьшую сумму цифр. Это 10 в какой-то степени, степень есссно равна количеству нулей на хвосте.

Answer (score 1):

Примерный алгоритм

```
# функция определения суммы цифр числа
def sum_digits(a):
    res = 0

    while a != 0:
        res += a % 10
        a /= 10

    return res


# функция определения является ли число a лучше числа b
def is_best(a, b):
    sum_a = sum_digits(a)
    sum_b = sum_digits(b)

    if sum_a > sum_b:
        return True

    if sum_a == sum_b:
        return a < b

    return False


# основной функционал
n = int(input())

worst = 1

for value in range(2, n + 1):
    # рассматривать только делители числа n
    if n % value == 0:
        # найти худшее число
        if not is_best(value, worst):
            worst = value

print(worst)
```

Comment: Увидела у себя ошибку, спасибо

Comment: @fox_price, в чем была то?

Comment: Ошибка в определении "лучшего" числа. Теперь исправил. Сейчас не проходит по времени, но думаю, скоро придумаю как это сделать

Comment: Получится ускорить код, если искать делители до корня n?

Comment: @fox_price, нет конечно - пример - число 10, но 5 - делитель и 10 делитель :) вам же не простые делители нужны - для простых корень из n хватило бы

Comment: Да, сам понял...
Печально(((

Comment: @fox_price, `Да, сам понял... Печально(((` однако вы можете в 2 раза ускорить рассмотрев только до `n/2` включительно и отдельно `n` рассмотреть

Comment: @fox_price, вторая оптимизация, которая еще в 2 раза ускорит программу - не надо каждый раз вычислять кол-во цифр для 2 чисел, для `worst` можно и запомнить и использовать, а вычислять только для текущего слова

Comment: Спасибо) Очень помогли))

Comment: @Zhihar даже если бы нужны были только простые делители числа, то прохода до ```sqrt(n)``` не хватит. Т.к. ```sqrt(10)```=3.16..., а 5 > 3.

Answer (score 0):

вообще код какой-то кривоватый

ваш код умеет выводить только или 1 или само число, а в задаче вопрос про делители числа, т.е. ваш ответ никаких иных делителей принципиально не выводит

поэтому и тест валится - ведь в тесте 4 скорее всего результат - один из делителей (для 10 например 2 или 5)

Почему бы вам не переписать алгоритм так (в лоб):

1. найти все делители числа n и записать их в список
2. создать функцию проверки на "лучшесть" из 2 чисел
3. сделать проход по всем делителям (т.е. будет выполнено n^2 проходов) и сравнить с остальными делителями

**P.S.**

предложенный алгоритм имел сложность O(n^2), но это я погорячился :)

лучше подойдет такой алгоритм:

1. идем по числу `m` от `2` до `n` и определяем, что число является делителем `n`
2. сравниваем делитель `m` с предыдущем делителем `m_prev` через функцию "лучшести" и если число лучше предыдущего, то записываем его в `m_prev`

в итоге сложность такой задачи будет O(n), что гораздо лучше

и никаких лишних списков заполнять не надо

ну и цикл от 2, потому что `m_prev = 1`

и кстати тогда проверку надо на то, что пользователь ввел `1` и тогда выдать сразу ответ - `1`

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: @fox_price, я в коммент за P.S. получше алгоритм добавил, побыстрее

Comment: Не получается...
Сейчас немного по другому попробую

Comment: Помогите, пожалуйста,кодом, чтобы наглядно посмотреть свои ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно:

```
def main(n):
    for i in range(len(str(n))):
        k = 10**i
        if not n % k:
            worst = k
    return worst

n = int(input())
print(main(n))
```